# Text tokenization with Stanford NLP : Filter unrequired words and characters

Tags: java, machine-learning, tokenize, stanford-nlp

I use `Stanford NLP` for string tokenization in my classification tool. I want to get only meaningful words, but I get non-word tokens (like `---`, `>`, `.` etc.) and not important words like `am`, `is`, `to` (stop words). Does anybody know a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very domain-specific task that we don't perform for you in CoreNLP. You should be able to make this work with a regular expression filter and a [stopword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) filter on top of the CoreNLP tokenizer.

Here's [an example list of English stopwords](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link. And what about non-word tokens like ---, >, .?

Comment: `String[] words = instring.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");`

Answer (score 8):

In stanford Corenlp, there is a [stopword removal annotator](https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp) which provides the functionality to remove the standord stopwords. You can also define custom stopwords here as per your need (i.e ---,<,. etc)

You can see the example [here](https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp/blob/master/src/test/java/intoxicant/analytics/coreNlp/StopwordAnnotatorTest.java):

```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, stopword");
   props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.stopword", "intoxicant.analytics.coreNlp.StopwordAnnotator");

   StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
   Annotation document = new Annotation(example);
   pipeline.annotate(document);
   List<CoreLabel> tokens = document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);
```

Here in the above example "tokenize,ssplit,stopwords" are set as custom stopwords.

Hope it'll help you....!!

Comment: How can I download jar file of intoxicant.analytics.coreNlp.StopwordAnnotator?

Comment: Look like intoxicant.analytics.coreNlP doesn't compile from github, no artifact available on maven central and no commit since 3 years. Dead project ?